# PVC In pending state in eks

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, kubernetes-pvc

I have this storage classes

```
k get sc                                                                                                                                                      
NAME            PROVISIONER             RECLAIMPOLICY   VOLUMEBINDINGMODE      ALLOWVOLUMEEXPANSION   AGE
gp2             kubernetes.io/aws-ebs   Delete          WaitForFirstConsumer   false                  45d
gp3 (default)   kubernetes.io/aws-ebs   Delete          Immediate              true                   19h
```

I created a pvc

```
 k describe pvc data-sonarqube-postgresql-0                                                                                                                             
Name:          data-sonarqube-postgresql-0
Namespace:     sonarqube-dce
StorageClass:  gp3
Status:        Pending
Volume:
Labels:        app.kubernetes.io/instance=sonarqube
               app.kubernetes.io/name=postgresql
               role=primary
Annotations:   volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner: ebs.csi.aws.com
               volume.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner: ebs.csi.aws.com
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:
Access Modes:
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Used By:       sonarqube-postgresql-0
Events:
  Type     Reason                Age                    From                                                                                      Message
  ----     ------                ----                   ----                                                                                      -------
  Warning  ProvisioningFailed    11m (x265 over 19h)    ebs.csi.aws.com_ebs-csi-controller-74b8b88ff9-9vngf_2fdc4610-b19f-4b1a-98a2-f3c7795528d4  failed to provision volume with StorageClass "gp3": rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded
  Normal   ExternalProvisioning  2m5s (x4704 over 19h)  persistentvolume-controller                                                               Waiting for a volume to be created either by the external provisioner 'ebs.csi.aws.com' or manually by the system administrator. If volume creation is delayed, please verify that the provisioner is running and correctly registered.
  Normal   Provisioning          54s (x281 over 19h)    ebs.csi.aws.com_ebs-csi-controller-74b8b88ff9-9vngf_2fdc4610-b19f-4b1a-98a2-f3c7795528d4  External provisioner is provisioning volume for claim "sonarqube-dce/data-sonarqube-postgresql-0"
```

I see this error

```
k logs ebs-csi-controller-74b8b88ff9-9vngf -n kube-system -f                                                                                                     
Defaulted container "ebs-plugin" out of: ebs-plugin, csi-provisioner, csi-attacher, csi-snapshotter, csi-resizer, liveness-probe
I0315 11:29:02.332218       1 driver.go:83] "Driver Information" Driver="ebs.csi.aws.com" Version="v1.28.0"
I0315 11:29:02.332326       1 controller.go:92] "batching" status=true
E0316 18:55:57.576817       1 driver.go:155] "GRPC error" err=<
    rpc error: code = Internal desc = Could not create volume "pvc-20c83eb1-1afd-4a5f-8aa1-e83773edd9f2": could not create volume in EC2: RequestCanceled: request context canceled
    caused by: context deadline exceeded
 >
E0316 18:55:57.578242       1 driver.go:155] "GRPC error" err=<
    rpc error: code = Internal desc = Could not create volume "pvc-73e37c32-a8b3-4e55-bd1b-6819cf539420": could not create volume in EC2: RequestCanceled: request context canceled
    caused by: context deadline exceeded
 >
E0316 18:55:57.581023       1 driver.go:155] "GRPC error" err=<
    rpc error: code = Internal desc = Could not create volume "pvc-9a44c928-843e-4b61-a70f-d8acbc3aea06": could not create volume in EC2: RequestCanceled: request context canceled
    caused by: context canceled
 >
E0316 18:55:57.584137       1 driver.go:155] "GRPC error" err=<
    rpc error: code = Internal desc = Could not create volume "pvc-ab704102-de62-40f5-91a6-c7865c2b011e": could not create volume in EC2: RequestCanceled: request context canceled
    caused by: context deadline exceeded
```

How can I resolve this one

I have installed the add on on eks 1.28 via tf. the pods are up and running

How can I mitigate the issue?

Comment: ebs.csi.aws.com cannot create the volume, maybe you can create it manually to get it working.  But, is  the provisioner running and correctly registered as mentioned in the event ?

Comment: why it can't create the volume? I want to provision It dynamically?

Comment: What is the read/write value for the drive you want to create? Can you make it ReadWriteOnce and see if that helps?

Comment: I did that ReadWriteOnce but nothing works